# iOS add straighten effect to image

Tags: ios

In my iOS project , I am using [CLImageEditor](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor). I have to add straighten effect in to that. Can any one please help me how to make "straighten" effect?

Comment: Do you just mean rotation or also perspective?

Comment: rotation with perspective. Just like apple camera view

Comment: I don't know about perspective in apple camera view. Here is [what I mean](http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/4d/57/ba/4d57bab0-7ffd-c411-a17a-6e9ebfc98a60/screen800x500.jpeg) by perspective.

Comment: ya. I want to say like that. Can you please provide me any example for this?

Comment: Take a look at CATransform3D, just seatch SO for "[objective-c] image perspective".

Answer (score 0):

Add `QuartzCore.framework`

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Here is some basic code for rotation, perspective and scale.

```
CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;

// Rotate
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, rotate, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

// Perspective
// mysterious multiplier m34
//    m34 = -1.0 / 500, 500 being somewhat the size of the view
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = .02;

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0.0f , 0.0f, translate);

// Scale
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DScale(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, scale, scale, 1.0f);

layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

Comment: @user3897036 If you want a CATransform3D sample code project email.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. [CLImageEditor](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor) is the api that I am using. Here is the [link](http://s16.postimg.org/9x4mfueh1/unnamed.png) for the effect, that I need for my project.

Comment: That seems to just be rotation, sizing and cropping. The rotation and sixing can be done with `CGAffineTransform`.